# Android Local files that were deleted reappear when the app is installed after a Clean

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I have written a Xamarin Android App using Visual Studio that creates Estimates.  At different times, I save the Estimate locally.  If you try to reopen the Estimate, it tries the local file and if it doesn't exist, it tries the server. 
Once the Estimate is saved successfully to the server, I delete the local file.  Here is the code.

```
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Settings.DocumentsPath, fileName);
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            StreamWriter opf = new StreamWriter(filePath, false);
            try
            {
                ser.Serialize(opf, obj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.Error(ex);
            }
            opf.Close();
```

Settings.DocumentsPath is set as such:

```
   private static string _DocumentsPath = null;
    public static string DocumentsPath
    {
        get
        {
            _DocumentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            return _DocumentsPath;
        }
    }
```

When I load an Estimate, I first check to see if there is a local copy and loads that one if it exists.  Otherwise it makes a call to the server.  When the Estimate is successfully saved to the server, I use the following code to delete the local file:

```
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Settings.DocumentsPath, FName);
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.Error(ex);
        }
    }
```

This works.  Subsequent calls to open the Estimate try the local file, but it is not there so the request is made from the server.

The problem is that after doing all this, if I clean my project and run it again, an old version of the local saved Estimate shows back up.  When the Estimate is loaded then, it finds the old local version of the Estimate and doesn't send a request to the server.  I can completely uninstall the app from the tablet and reinstall it and the older local files come back.  Is there a better place to store local files other than Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal?  If there a setting somewhere in Visual Studio that prevents it from restoring those local files when the app is being deployed for debug?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting for backups, that you can disable in the AndroidManifest within the application tag:

`android:allowBackup="true"`

> android:allowBackup Whether to allow the application to participate in
>   the backup and restore infrastructure. If this attribute is set to
>   false, no backup or restore of the application will ever be performed,
>   even by a full-system backup that would otherwise cause all
>   application data to be saved via adb. The default value of this
>   attribute is true.